# Set path of Header files to avoid using relative paths (VS2015/c++)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

H, i'm trying to set my project up so that i can avoid using relative paths for my header files in my project. The reason is that the project is multi-platform and I would like to avoid restructuring each use dependent on which system it's compiled on.

Currently, the header files do not use the correct path way and the only way i can use the includes is if i set relative paths to the files.

E.G.

for my file render.h i want to use:

```
#include "math/matrix.h" <--- this doesn't work
```

but

```
#include "../math/matrix.h" <--this works
```

What would i be doing incorrectly here for setting up the project?

in the Properties page, i have set up the following

VC++ Directories -> Include Directories -> C:\Game\math

C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\Game\math

If i right click on the .cpp files and go to properties, i have the C\C++ options but the Headers do not.

Answer (score 1):

If your file resides in `C:\Game\math\matrix.h`, then an Include Directory of `C:\Game\math` and `#include` directive of `"math/matrix.h"`, would produce a concatenated result of `C:\Game\math\math/matrix.h`. You simply need to change your Include Directory to be `C:\Game` (or your `#include` to be only `"matrix.h"`).

Also, generally you set include directories per-project, not per source (.cpp) file. The reason that the header files do not have C++ compilation options is that they are not compiled - only the sources are compiled.